# Google Chrome Extension Override !important

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to modify a website's layout but sometimes the website uses !important, is there a way of overriding this? I can't seem to figure out how to load the css content script after the page's css file(s).

Comment: Do you need to completely override the original CSS or just modify certain elements/classes ? E.g. would it be OK to get rid of the original CSS entirely (as if it never existed) ?

Answer (score 4):

An `!important` CSS rule can be overridden by:

1. Another `!important` rule contained in a ruleset that uses the same selector but is evaluated **after** the original ruleset you're trying to override.
2. Another `!important` rule contained in a ruleset that uses a selector that matches the element you're trying to modify but is more specific than original ruleset selector you're trying to override.

---

For example if a website has a rule for all menu items:

```
#menu span {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

You can override this rule by using the very same selector `#menu span` but need to make sure your rules are injected after the website's stylesheets. In a chrome-extension's [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) that could be achieved by injecting your content at `document_idle`:

```
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyle.css"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
  ...
```

Alternatively you can inject a rule with a more specific selector:

```
#menu span.menu-item {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
```